# How do you uninstall Windows 8 apps that are not on the start screen?

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, windows-store-app

If an app is on the start screen, I can right click it and choose "Uninstall" to uninstall it.

But if I have previously chosen "Unpin from Start" for an app, so that the app is no longer on the start screen, then how can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, then search for the name of the app. When it pops up, you can right click on it and press `Uninstall` from the bar below (just as if it was on the start screen).

Sample screenshot:

[image]

[Larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAAMq.png)

Answer (score 1):

Press `Windows key` + 'X' , then press 'F'. This will bring up 'Programs and Features' in the 'Control Panel'.

Then, same as in previous Windows, select any app you want to uninstall and click 'Uninstall/Change'.

Comment: Start + X ? Then F. What is that supposed to do? Start+X gives me mobility centre...

Comment: @ppumkin I have edited to clarify.

Comment: Windows+X should give you the "power menu" with Power Tools and Admin Tools. @Kang - The Programs and Features list doesn't include the "modern ui" app store apps however - at least not on Windows RT.